# XML equivalent of @Configurable annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Is there any XML equivalent of @Configurable annotation?

For example for the bean:

```
<bean class="org.obliquid.sherd.domain.SalesDocument" scope ="prototype">
    <property name="docType" ref="documentTypeProto"/>
</bean>
```

How can I tell that SalesDocument should be @Configurable?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you need enhanced configuration support in spring, have a look at Constretto: https://github.com/constretto/constretto-core

Answer (score 4):

No - the purpose of `@Configurable` to inject properties into objects that are not Spring beans.  In your example `SalesDocument` is already a Spring bean, and `docType` will be injected.

Comment: Not if I create it with new inside a DAO, though.

Comment: In that case, don't use new, use applicationContext.getBean("salesDocument")

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to simply do this out of the box that I'm aware of.

One approach to achieve what you want is to look at using Spring AspectJ based AOP extensions. It'll be a lot of work, but if you know that your DAOs need limited configuration (probably the just the `EntityManager`?) it might be doable.

Look [at the spring reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) for details.