# Xml replcement for @Configurable annotation

Tags: spring, configurable

I am java developer and I use your framework "Spring" 
in my application. I have a problem and I have not found 
clear answer on Spring official documentation and on any forum.

Problem description.

We have two classes:

```
public class A {
...
...
}


public class B {
private A a;

public void setA(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}

....
....
}
```

I want use dependency injection mechanism form Spring and inject class A to B when B is created.
Class B is not managed by Spring, when I create class `B` I use `new` operator, I looked to Spring 
documentation and I have found `@Configurable` and AspectJ solution, it all work when I have access to 
source code of class B and I can put annotation

```
@Configurable
public class B {
....
....
}
```

My problem is, I don't have access to source code of class B (let say it comes from some outside library) 
and I can't put annotation `@Configurable`. Can I replace `@Configurable` by some XML definition in xml configuration
file. I haven't found answer for that in Spring documentation (only `@Configurable` annotation example)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346509/xml-equivalent-of-configurable-annotation-in-spring) SO question.

I would suggest that you use `@Configurable` as an absolutely last resort. It introduces complexity that in most cases can be avoided using regular Spring configuration.